# react-native-vision-camera error "Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file"

Tags: react-native

I am facing an issue while trying to build my React Native project using the react-native-vision-camera package. The build process fails with the following error message:

```
BUILD FAILED in 17s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081   

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vision-camera'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\ddark\desenvolvimento\Javascript\mobile\lura\node_modules\react-native-vision-camera\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\ddark\.gradle\caches\7.5.1\scripts\2xyn2wtrziu6kfd47b1k22842).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

    at makeError (C:\Users\ddark\desenvolvimento\Javascript\mobile\lura\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\ddark\desenvolvimento\Javascript\mobile\lura\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)     
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\ddark\desenvolvimento\Javascript\mobile\lura\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\ddark\desenvolvimento\Javascript\mobile\lura\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This error seems to be related to the Java version used for the build, as indicated by the "Unsupported class file major version 64" message. However, I am using Java 8 (JDK 1.8), which is compatible with React Native.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,
antonio lugogo

I was hoping the React Native application would compile successfully!